# SNIMissingWarning & InsecurePlatformWarning in Python on Bash Windows 10 Subsystem

Tags: windows-10, bash, python

I really enjoy running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10, but I noticed that python often spits out warnings. How do I go about resolve these warnings? Thanks

By the way, the links from the warnings only tell you what these warnings mean, but there are on instructions on how to properly resolve them. The documentation actually shows that you can disable_warnings(), but I don't think that's the best practice.

```
(cv) antony@ThinkPad:~$ pip freeze
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
decorator==4.0.10
enum34==1.1.6
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
numpy==1.11.3
pathlib2==2.1.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
prompt-toolkit==1.0.9
ptyprocess==0.5.1
Pygments==2.1.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
traitlets==4.3.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
/home/antony/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/antony/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```